# Cypress with typescript custom commands type error

Tags: typescript, cypress, e2e-testing

I've setup custom commands for my Cypress tests :

```
// cypress/support/commands.ts
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

Cypress.Commands.add('getByTestId', (target: [string], timeout: number = 0) => {
    target[0] = `[data-testid="${target[0]}"]`;
    return cy.get(target.join('>'), { timeout });
});



// cypress/support/index.ts
/// <reference types="cypress" />
declare global {
namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
        getByTestId(id: string): Chainable<Element>;
    }
  }
}
```

these are my files where I setup my commands.

When writing test I have this error even if I had this on the top of my file `/// <reference types="cypress" />` :

```
cypress/integration/filename.test.e2e.ts
```

[image: sample.test.e2e.ts]

Answer (score 2):

I also have Cypress TypeScript support and ran into some issues at the beginning. The following setup worked for me:

```
// cypress/plugins/index.ts
/// <reference types="cypress" />

// cypress/support/commands.ts
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    getByTestId(selector: string, ...options: any): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
  }
}

// cypress/support/commands.ts
Cypress.Commands.add('getByTestId', (selector, ...options) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-test=${selector}]`, ...options);
});
```

So I have the type reference in the *plugins/index.ts* file and the namespace declaration as well as custom command definitions in *support/commands.ts*. I am using the currently newest Cypress version 9.3.1.

Additionally, another thing I've also noticed is when you try to import stuff into *commands.ts*, you will also get the error you described.

Comment: This answer helped me resolve a similar issue with custom commands in version 11.2.0
There is no `plugins/index.ts ` file after V10 so I added the namespace declaration to the

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
// tsconfig.json

"include": [
    "cypress/support/*.ts"
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).